# Transforming list to data frame with related data points in same row

Tags: r, dataframe, list, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a list that represents field of research information of a single publication. I want to combine the list to a data.frame such that each 2-digit code is stored in a "division" column and each 4-digit code in a "group" column. When the first two digits are shared, the division and group should be stored in the same row. I apologize for the bad title.

```
my_list <- list(
  list(id = "80067", name = "3403 Macromolecular and Materials Chemistry"),
  list(id = "80011", name = "40 Engineering"),
  list(id = "80005", name = "34 Chemical Sciences")
)
```

Desired output:

```
data.frame(division = c("40 Engineering", "34 Chemical Sciences"), 
           group = c(NA, "3403 Macromolecular and Materials Chemistry"))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First `unlist` your `my_list` into a vector, then `enframe` it into a two-column dataframe. `filter` to only include the `name` column, then assign `group` and `prefix` (for grouping into same row) by the patterns of digit. Finally reshape the structure from "long" to "wide".

```r
library(tidyverse)

unlist(my_list) %>% 
  enframe() %>% 
  filter(name == "name") %>% 
  mutate(group = ifelse(str_count(value, "\\d") == 4, "group", "division"), 
         prefix = str_extract(value, "^\\d{2}"), .keep = "used") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = group, values_from = value)
```

---

Update: The above code can be simplified by a bit if we use `bind_rows` (inspired by @akrun's answer) at the beginning:

```r
bind_rows(my_list) %>% 
  mutate(group = ifelse(str_count(name, "\\d") == 4, "group", "division"), 
         prefix = str_extract(name, "^\\d{2}"), .keep = "used") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = group, values_from = name)
```

---

### Output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  prefix group                                       division            
  <chr>  <chr>                                       <chr>               
1 34     3403 Macromolecular and Materials Chemistry 34 Chemical Sciences
2 40     NA                                          40 Engineering                                        40 Engineering
```

Comment: Very nice. Thank you! I was not aware of the .keep argument.

Answer (score 3):

We could use `bind_rows` to create a data.frame and then do a grouping by substring to extract the components

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
 bind_rows(my_list) %>%
  group_by(grp = substr(name, 1, 2)) %>%
   summarise(group = str_extract(name, "^\\d{4}\\s+(.*)"), 
     division = name, .groups = "keep") %>% 
  filter(any(!is.na(group)) & !is.na(group) | n() == 1) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
 select(division, group)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  division                                    group                                      
  <chr>                                       <chr>                                      
1 3403 Macromolecular and Materials Chemistry 3403 Macromolecular and Materials Chemistry
2 40 Engineering                              <NA>
```